# Wave-like description of Compton scattering and photoelectric effect

Tags: electrons, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, photoelectric-effect

I have found in the wikipedia page for [QFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory) the following statement:

> ... Although the photoelectric effect and Compton scattering strongly suggest the existence of the photon, it is now understood that they can be explained without invoking a quantum electromagnetic field ...

But there are no references. Can somebody provide a reference or guideline to do this? I am looking for a proper description with mathematical form.

Comment: Doesn't the wikipedia page mention the paper by Lamb and Scully about "The photoelectric effects without photons"?

Comment: No, it does not mention it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in the comment by @CuriousOne, there is indeed a paper providing such explanation (["The photoelectric effect without photons" by Lamb and Scully](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19690054849)).

It was however later found to be faulty. A very good review and references on this can be found in [these answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68147/can-the-photoelectric-effect-be-explained-without-photons) to a different question posted on this website, but apparently there is no consensus on the validity of the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I've been collecting wave theory explanations of QM phenomena for years. The photo-electric effect is the easiest one. The much-talked about frequency dependence is an obvious consequence of the Schroedinger equation. The Compton effect is different: here, the coupling between the e-m field and the electron states is not controlled by the shared frequency of the two systems, but by the shared wavelength. Schroedinger published a very simple paper in 1927 pointing this out, but he was howled down by the Copenhagen school. I thought I would win the Nobel Prize when I figured this out ten years ago, so I was disappointed to find my explanation was the same as Schroedingers.

Schroedinger was however baffled by the flecks of silver on a photographic plate from the light of a distant star. I have come up with an original explanation of this called "Quantum Siphoning". You have to start be realizing the photographic plate is not exactly a passive source in the sense that it needs to absorb a full "quantum" of energy to record a transition. The loophole that nobody else figured out is that at the very tiny concentrations of metallic silver needed to create a developable photographic image, the thermodynamics actually favors the transition.

All of these arguments can be found on my blog, and they are mostly linked from this recent article, "[There Are No Pea-Shooters For Photons](http://marty-green.blogspot.ca/2016/02/there-are-no-pea-shooters-for-photons.html)."