# Do photons have relativistic mass?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, mass

I am conducting research on photons and was wondering if they have relativistic mass. I already know that they they have zero rest mass. Any answers are welcome!

Comment: Did you look at the relativistic energy-momentum relationship?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation

Comment: If you are researching photons, I recommend [this article](http://www-3.unipv.it/fis/tamq/Anti-photon.pdf) by Nobel laureate Willis Lamb.  It discusses the history of the photon concept, and the misconceptions around the concept. (Like Lamb, I avoid the use of the word as much as possible.)

Comment: @garyp: Lamb was a Nobel Prize winner and also a kook. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68147/ . In any case, he has zero relevance here.

Comment: The relevance to my *comment* (not *answer*) is that the OP is conducting research on photons, and Lamb's article provides a history of the concept. There's nothing kooky about his Anit-photon paper.  As for your dismissal of his analysis of the photoelectric effect: [not so fast](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/131483/5739).  I don't know if Lamb was a kook or not, but in the two cases considered here, he is not.  But I'm with you on one thing.  It's easy to come up with a list of Nobel laureates who *are* kooks.

Answer (score 17):

Relativistic mass is obsolete. See [Why is there a controversy on whether mass increases with speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133376/why-is-there-a-controversy-on-whether-mass-increases-with-speed) . Therefore this is not a question that modern physicists would consider of interest. Furthermore, the usual motivation given for using the relativistic mass convention is that it lets you use Newton's second law without modification, but Newton's second law isn't going to apply to a photon, no matter how hard you try.

If you did want to assign a photon a relativistic mass, there is no other parameter that could determine the mass besides its energy $E$, and based on units the mass would then have to be of the form $m=kE/c^2$, where $k$ is a unitless constant. Probably $k=1$, since we can take $p=mv$ as the definition of the relativistic mass, and $p=E/c$ for a photon.

Answer (score -3):

It's quite wrong to assert that relativistic mass is obsolete. Gary Oas of Standford university did a study of a sample of the SR and GR textbooks. Of the ones published between 1995 and 2005 there were 60% of them which use relativistic mass.

In this video, Alan H. Guth of MIT describes why the mass of a photon is not zero.
http://www.newenglandphysics.org/common_misconceptions/DSC_0003.MOV

Comment: Curiously [another answer of Ben's](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133376/) cites the Oas paper and comes to the exact *opposite* conclusion as you have.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment to an answer. And, relativistic mass is obsolete.

Comment: Broken link. Roche (2005) also says exactly the opposite - that 60% of authors no longer use it. http://www.marco-learningsystems.com/pages/roche/what-is-mass.pdf