# Frequency of photon and frequency of EM wave

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons

If I have a source of photons where photons have $f$ frequency and the emitting frequency of the source is $f'$, what is the frequency of the resulting EM wave?

> Essentially, we have a source that emits photons that each have a
>   frequency of f, but the frequency of their production by the source is
>   f′.

Comment: What do you mean by *the emitting frequency of the source*? If the source is emitting light with a frequency $f$ then I don't understand what $f'$ is. Do you mean the source is modulating the light intensity at a frequency $f'$?

Comment: I mean every single photon is emitted after another with f' frequency. But the own frequency of the photon is f. Think like a gun that shots with f' frequency the bullets

Comment: Is the source moving?

Comment: See [What exactly does the *frequency* of a photon mean?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303458)

Comment: No the source is fixed.

Comment: A light wave isn't made up of photons as if it was a stream of little balls of light, and it doesn't make sense to talk about a source emitting one photon every $1/f'$ seconds. The average power can correspond to $h\nu$ every $1/f$ seconds but that isn't the same as emitting a photon every $1/f$ seconds.

Comment: See [What is the relation between electromagnetic wave and photon?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90646/what-is-the-relation-between-electromagnetic-wave-and-photon) for more on this.

Comment: " Light is not a wave nor a particle but instead it is an excitation in a quantum field. "

The QFT says what is this field phisically (apart mathematical objects)? There are theories that see this field like it was an excitation of spacetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're saying that you have a source that emits photons that each have a frequency of $f$, but the frequency of their production by the source is $f'$.

Well, then the frequency of the emitted waves is the same as the frequency of the photons, i.e. $f$. The rate of their emission doesn't matter.

Comment: This answer is basically correct but of course there is no such source that actually emits photons with a specific frequency of production.