# Photoelectric experiment explaining particle property of light

Tags: visible-light, wave-particle-duality, photoelectric-effect

How does photoelectric experiment prove the particle aspect of light in opposed to be solely wave-like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the photoelectric effect be explained without photons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68147/can-the-photoelectric-effect-be-explained-without-photons)

Comment: The particle aspect of a light with photons is fairly self-explanatory. What’s hard to explain is a light wave. Billions of coherent photons radiating from a common source resemble a wave but they are still individual particles.

Comment: @BillAlsept This must be some joke.

Comment: @my2cts you can physically describe and explain light with particles. You cannot even begin to describe a light wave without incorporating billions of individual photons.

Answer (score 1):

There was a zinc plate that when irradiated with ultraviolet light emitted electrons (charged particles) to a detector which could detect them. It was observed that there was a minimum energy to the light before the photoelectric effect could be observed. It was postulated that photons come in wavepackets. Planck relation gives: $E = h \nu$

Maybe this diagram helps:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect#/media/File:Photoelectric_effect_-_stopping_voltage_diagram_for_zinc_-_English.svg