# Why photoelectric effect proves particle nature?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, atomic-physics, photoelectric-effect

If a giant water wave can change the altitude of a boat, then why can't electron's position be changed by waves.

Afterall waves can make a ball rise and fall thus imparting energy to it.

Comment: Because the photoelectric effect has a cutoff frequency corresponding to the minimum kinetic energy of a photon needed to ionize an electron completely. No matter the intensity of the incoming light, there is zero photoelectric effect when the frequency is too low. This is incompatible with a wave description.

Comment: but could a wave also ionize an atom?

Comment: For a classical wave the energy of the wave is proportional to the amplitude of the wave, not the frequency. That means that no matter what the frequency of the light is, as long as the amplitude (intensity) of the light is strong enough, we should see electrons flying off the metal. But that is not what is observed in reality.

Comment: so are electrons repelled by EM waves as light carries no charge?

Comment: In short how wave nature can repel electrons?

Comment: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html

Comment: From a modern point of view it does not, you can derive a cutoff frequency for emission when modelling the electromagnetic field classically and handling the bound electrons quantum mechanically. But this was not known back then, so the assumption was to assume the light is quantized (which turned out to be true as well ...)

Comment: Somewhat related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68147/80706 – TL;DR: The photoeffect does *not* prove the quantization of the em-field.

Comment: If you send FREE electrons through a slit experiment you will see a pattern form because the electrons are being guided by the billions of reflecting photons

Comment: @BillAlsept what?